# CSS Two preloader cause issue

Tags: css, preloader

I need to have mutliple preloader. One on the body and now I want to add another preloader before displaying a form. Here is my first preloader :

```
<body>
<div id="preloader">
        <div id="status">
            <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 74.4 81.9" width="300"
                 height="300" xml:space="preserve">
                <linearGradient id="fill" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
                    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#76B442">
                        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#76B442; #A7A8AA; #76B442" dur="1s"
                                 repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    </stop>

                    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#A7A8AA">
                        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#A7A8AA; #76B442; #A7A8AA" dur="1s"
                                 repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    </stop>
                </linearGradient>
                <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1.9,79.4c-1.5-1.5,0.3-4.7,8.2-14.2c4.8-5.7,10.1-12.3,11.9-14.6l3.3-4.1l-1.6-1.7
                        c-7.2-7.4-8.6-20.6-3-29.7C27.9,3.4,43.8-1.4,56.8,4.2c6,2.6,11.8,8,14.4,13.5c2.7,5.6,2.5,15.4-0.4,21.1
                        c-6.6,13-22.8,18.9-36.3,13.3c-2.2-1-4.1-1.3-4.4-1c-0.3,0.4-5.8,7-12.2,14.8C8.8,76.8,5.7,80,4.3,80C3.3,80,2.1,79.7,1.9,79.4
                        L1.9,79.4z M53.5,48.8c5.7-2,10.7-6.3,13.4-11.3c2.8-5.2,2.9-13.8,0.1-18.9c-4.5-8.4-12-12.8-21.9-12.8c-26.3,0-33.2,33.2-9,42.7
                        C42.2,50.9,47.3,51,53.5,48.8L53.5,48.8z"></path>
                </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
.
.
.
</body>
```

My second preloader :

```
<div id="preloader_form">
    <div id="status_form">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 74.4 81.9" width="300"
         height="300" xml:space="preserve">
        <linearGradient id="fill" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#76B442">
                <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#76B442; #A7A8AA; #76B442" dur="1s"
                         repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
            </stop>

            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#A7A8AA">
                <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#A7A8AA; #76B442; #A7A8AA" dur="1s"
                         repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <path fill="url(#fill)" d="M1.9,79.4c-1.5-1.5,0.3-4.7,8.2-14.2c4.8-5.7,10.1-12.3,11.9-14.6l3.3-4.1l-1.6-1.7
                c-7.2-7.4-8.6-20.6-3-29.7C27.9,3.4,43.8-1.4,56.8,4.2c6,2.6,11.8,8,14.4,13.5c2.7,5.6,2.5,15.4-0.4,21.1
                c-6.6,13-22.8,18.9-36.3,13.3c-2.2-1-4.1-1.3-4.4-1c-0.3,0.4-5.8,7-12.2,14.8C8.8,76.8,5.7,80,4.3,80C3.3,80,2.1,79.7,1.9,79.4
                L1.9,79.4z M53.5,48.8c5.7-2,10.7-6.3,13.4-11.3c2.8-5.2,2.9-13.8,0.1-18.9c-4.5-8.4-12-12.8-21.9-12.8c-26.3,0-33.2,33.2-9,42.7
                C42.2,50.9,47.3,51,53.5,48.8L53.5,48.8z"></path>
    </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<form>.......
```

Here is the CSS for both the preloader :

```
#preloader{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 120;
}

#preloader_form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 110;
}

#status,
#status_form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

I didn't have any issue with the first preloader. But the SVG of the second disappear when the first preloader disappear. And I don't understand why

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have all the `id` attributes in your code unique.

Comment: This is the case, as u can see in the code I posted. I just check, in case, and the id's are unique

Comment: `<linearGradient id="fill"` in both preloaders, as I can see.

Comment: Well, you're right... I don't check enough ahah. Thanks a lot !

Comment: happy to help =))